# Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio, Volley and ArcMenu

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an old volley configuration in my app. The app was built to target lollipop devices few years ago. I have also used an arcmenu library in same configuration like `compile project('volley')` and `compile project('arcmenu')`.

Recently, I have reopened that project and tried running it again but it gives me this error:

```
Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio
```

I have installed all the previous platforms, from 21 to 26 in my sdk. Here's my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.co.memoize"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.2'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.5.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'
compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
compile 'com.navercorp.pulltorefresh:library:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
//compile project(':volley')
compile project(':arcmenu')
}
```

After installing the platform versions, I get this message:

```
Error:Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

My settings.gradle file:

```
//include ':app', ':volley' commented to triangulate which library was 
    causing the problem but still not fixed
 include ':app'
 include ':arcmenu'
```

and arc menu gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue? Thanks

Comment: post the build.gradle in the arcmenu folder

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, I have added the files. Take a look

Comment: In any case move the apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by downloading and adding the dependencies as `.aar/.jar` files